# Issue performing concatenation in a volume in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am building a tumor segmentation deep learning model, about to use 3D Unet but I came up with this problem, here is my code:

```
# Convolutional Block
def conv_block(inputs, num_filters):
    x = Conv3D(num_filters, (3, 3, 3), padding = "same")(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    x = Conv3D(num_filters, (3, 3, 3), padding = "same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    return x

# Encoder Block
def encoder_block(inputs, num_filters):
    x = conv_block(inputs, num_filters)
    p = MaxPool3D((2, 2, 2))(x)
    return x, p

# Decoder Block
def decoder_block(inputs, skip, num_filters):
    x = Conv3DTranspose(num_filters, (2, 2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = Concatenate()([x, skip])
    x = conv_block(x, num_filters)
    return x

# UNET

def unet(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    "----ENCODER----"
    s1, p1 = encoder_block(inputs, 64)
    s2, p2 = encoder_block(p1, 128)
    s3, p3 = encoder_block(p2, 256)
    s4, p4 = encoder_block(p3, 512)

    "----BRIDGE---"
    b1 = conv_block(p4, 1024)

    "----DECODER----"
    d1 = decoder_block(b1, s4, 512)
    d2 = decoder_block(d1, s3, 256)
    d3 = decoder_block(d2, s2, 128)
    d4 = decoder_block(d3, s1, 64)

    outputs = Conv3D(1, 1, padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(d4)

    model = Model(inputs, outputs, name="UNET")
    return model

input_shape = (155, 255, 255, 3)

test_model = unet(input_shape)
```

And here is the issue:

```
<ipython-input-15-5ab5422e8c43> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 input_shape = (155, 255, 255, 3)
      2 
----> 3 test_model = unet(input_shape)

3 frames
<ipython-input-14-03345eb7b1a8> in unet(input_shape)
     14 
     15     "----DECODER----"
---> 16     d1 = decoder_block(b1, s4, 512)
     17     d2 = decoder_block(d1, s3, 256)
     18     d3 = decoder_block(d2, s2, 128)

<ipython-input-12-44442d65f832> in decoder_block(inputs, skip, num_filters)
      2 def decoder_block(inputs, skip, num_filters):
      3     x = Conv3DTranspose(num_filters, (2, 2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")(inputs)
----> 4     x = Concatenate()([x, skip])
      5     x = conv_block(x, num_filters)
      6     return x

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/layers/merging/concatenate.py in build(self, input_shape)
    129                 )
    130                 if len(unique_dims) > 1:
--> 131                     raise ValueError(err_msg)
    132 
    133     def _merge_function(self, inputs):

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 18, 30, 30, 512), (None, 19, 31, 31, 512)]
```

I don't know why the output layer sums a voxel and that is giving the error, I do not want to eliminate that voxel because it might be valuable information